# Can I use Enterprise License to deploy beta version of app to client?

Tags: iphone, ios

This question in related to iOS Developer Enterprise program
Our client wants to review the app on their phone before release. 
Can we buy an Enterprise License from our company and then use it to deploy the app? 
For Enterprise account, Apple talks about in-house deployment. Can it be a legal issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use Ad-hock deployment, which is just limited to 100 devices. Enterprise is an overkill for what you are looking for and it's quite a time consuming process to get the enterprise license.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I believe for an Ad-Hoc deployment I would have to add my client's UDID to provisioning portal and that is something we would like to avoid.

Comment: Technically, using the Enterprise program in this way goes against Apple's terms - as applications developed and published with it are **only** meant to be deployed the devices which are owned by devices which are owned by employees - a client doesn't come under this.

The best solution is to use a service like [TestFlight](http://www.testflightapp.com) or [Hockey](http://www.hockeyapp.net) to simplify the process for getting the client's UDIDs.